# EC2 freeze on installing NodeJS packages NPM/Yarn - AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am deploying a React + Express API app in EC2 `t2-micro` - Ubuntu with NGINX
The problem is when I try `npm i` (`node_modules` is not uploaded), the server freeze and I need to restart it. There is no response from SSH/FTP/HTTP. Via HTTP I am getting `504 timed out`.

In EC2 AWS Dashboard -> Monitoring, I see:

[image]

This is the `system log`:

> [   15.627070] cloud-init[847]: Cloud-init v. 20.3-......ubuntu1~20.04.1 finished at Fri, 22 Jan 20..... Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 15.60 seconds
> 20...: Amazon SSM Agent v3.0.161.0 is running
> 20....: OsProductName: Ubuntu
> 202....: OsVersion: 20.04

The `Instance Screenshot` works fine and I see the login console:
[image]

The `Status Checks` are passed and there is no failed at all. It is the same after 30 mins.

In the same time I can't access it via `HTTP` (`504 error`) or via `SSH` with Putty, where I see just an empty console with no symbols.

I have `Credit specification`  - `Enabled unlimited mode`.

I think, this is about the CPU usage/credits, but I don't know, how to figure out everything.
I can increase the instance type, but is it this the only solution ? For `t2-micro`, we are using a `free tier`.

Comment: You should note that by enabling unlimited mode, you may get charged for the instance. Overages from unlimited mode are not covered by free tier.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the note. It is enabled, but still it freezes

Comment: My guess is that in addition to consuming all CPU, the compilation is also consuming all the memory

Comment: t2.micro has only 1GB of ram. So this could also be an issue.

Comment: @gdfgdfg I am also facing same issue. Did you get the cause behind it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap  /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
swapon  --show
free -h
```

Found this [answer](https://fallocate%20-l%204G%20/swapfile%20chmod%20600%20/swapfile%20mkswap%20%20/swapfile%20swapon%20/swapfile%20swapon%20%20--show%20free%20-h)